# Executing a list of commands on distinct lines with bash -c?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I pass a list of commands to a bash script through an environment variable as shown in the example below:

```bash
CMDS='
    date > date.txt
    cat date.txt
    date | rev
' script
```

What is the correct way to execute these commands in the bash script ?

I did the following and it seams to work. Is it correct ?

```bash
#! /bin/bash
bash -c "$CMDS"
```

Comment: As long as the string CMDS is not using another `'` it should be correct. Example for a problematic CMDS string would be: `CMDS='echo "hello world"; echo ';echo $0'; echo "good bye"'`.

Comment: @paladin thank you very much. Is there a way to avoid this limitation ? I use this to filter forced commands in ssh authorized_keys file. I use a script that only accepts to execute commands listed in a file in the remote host.

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'` and escape everything which is problematic, like so: `CMDS="echo \"hello world\"; echo ';echo \$0'; echo \"good bye\""`.